# Missing function ST_Extent in PostGIS db

Tags: postgis, mapnik

I hope you can help as I am tearing my hair out here. Do any of you elite geo peeps have any idea why some specific functions could be missing from my PostGIS install?

I am trying to use Mapnik with PostGIS but when I try to run queries from Python it fails with an error of:

```
ERROR:  function st_extent(geography) does not exist at character 73
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
STATEMENT:  SELECT ST_XMin(ext),ST_YMin(ext),ST_XMax(ext),ST_YMax(ext) FROM (SELECT ST_Extent(geom) as ext from reseller_map_core_reseller) as tmp
```

This is the part of the mapnik code:

```
shapes = mapnik.Layer('Geometry from PostGIS')
shapes.datasource = mapnik.PostGIS(host='localhost', user='user', password='password', dbname='sales_map', table='sales_map_core_sales', geometry_field='geom', srid='4326')
shapes.styles.append('My Style')
m.layers.append(shapes)
```

I'm just trying to overlay all of the regions from the selected table onto my mapnik generated image.

I have installed PostGIS successfully, created a spatial db using extensions and my other GeoDjango/PostGIS seems to work so far.

I have looked in the db using pgAdmin and I can see that the st_extents() is missing from the list for some reason even though the others *seem* to be there.

Any ideas why this specific function (and possibly others) could be missing when I have installed everything?

I am using:

- PostGIS: 2.0.3
- Postgresql: 9.2.3
- Mapnik 2.10

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most likely `st_extent` is not missing -> it is just undefined for **geography** types (that's what your error says).

It works on **geometry** types:

```
osm=# select st_extent('LINESTRING(1 2,3 4)'::geography);
ERROR:  function st_extent(geography) does not exist
LINE 1: select st_extent('LINESTRING(1 2,3 4)'::geography);
           ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.


osm=# select st_extent('LINESTRING(1 2,3 4)'::geometry);
  st_extent   
--------------
 BOX(1 2,3 4)
(1 row)
```

Comment: Genius! That was it! I'm new to db functions so I didn't quite realise what the eror was telling me and then was confused because I couldn't find it in the function list when viewing the db (but obviously it's there somewhere because it's working now). Thanks!